# Non negative function in python

Tags: python, julia

i have got one small problem with a code, is how to express the command 'nonneg' in python for example i want to make sure if i use this function correctly or there is another way to declare it

```
for i in oc[1]:
    x1 = x0 + oc[:, i]
    if nonneg(x1):
        xls.append(x1)
```

`x0` is a vector or an array the same thing for `x1` and `xls`

Comment: Presumably you'll want to use numpy but it's not clear to me what you're asking. You should include a python example for the input and expected output

Comment: That would be fine, if I knew Julia. If you are going to add an example, please do so in an [edit] not as a comment, it will be illegible

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't ignore it but i misunderstood it.

Comment: how does the `julia` tag relate to this question?

Comment: i was writing a julia example to express what i want to do at first then i edited my post and gave a part of the code that i'm trying to write to make sure weather i'm on the right path or not and you can tell if you saw the function `nonneg()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using numpy, you can check whether all of the elements of an an array are non-negative like this:

```
import numpy as np

def nonneg(array):
    return not np.any(array < 0)

print(nonneg(np.array([1, 1])))  # True
print(nonneg(np.array([0, 1])))  # True
print(nonneg(np.array([-1, 1]))) # False
```

If you're using plain-Python iterables (i.e., `list` or `tuple`, or similar), you can do

```
def nonneg(lst):
    return not any(element < 0 for element in lst)

print(nonneg([1, 1]))  # True
print(nonneg([0, 1]))  # True
print(nonneg([-1, 1])) # False
```

In both cases, we're just explicitly asking the question: "are any of the elements of the array negative?", then flipping the answer to get whether any elements are **non**-negative. For numpy, we take advantage of array-wide operations, while for the plain Python version we need to iterate over the elements manually.